# Eclipse plugin: how to read the "settings.xml" file path which is configured in M2Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

Now I'm developing a new Eclipse plugin, in this plugin I need to get the settings.xml file which is configured in m2Eclipse plugin and update it. I want to know whether the m2eclipse plugin has provided the related extension point so that I can use directly.

I've researched its user guide and the website, I cannot find any useful information for resolving my problem.

P.s: I'm not saying how to configure the settings.xml in maven plugin but developing a new plugin to read the settings.xml in m2eclipse.

Comment: What do you mean by 'm2eclipse plugin has provided the related extension point'? There are more standard ways to find out about extension points.

Comment: @greg-449 I want to get the settings.xml file configured in Eclipse maven plugin (m2eclipse),  so I need to know whether the m2eclipse has provide the ability or API so that I can get the settings.xml file. Is the explanation clear? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have access to the user settings.xml path via

> MavenPlugin.getMavenConfiguration().getUserSettingsFile()

And the global settings via

> MavenPlugin.getMavenConfiguration().getGlobalSettingsFile()

Comment: Hi Fred, could you also tell how can I import the MavenPlugin?  Which bundle or package  I need to import?